# Ajaxtool kit popup in usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

i have page in which i used the usercontrol in user control i use a ajaxtoll kit popup window to load a div in the user control it is working as expected when the pase ispostback is false that is for the first time when the page loads. but after the post back when i invoked the popup it is giving me some unspecified javascript error.

Thanks

Comment: what is the error you are receiving??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the name of the control is correct since you will have that div inside a user control?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had the same problem that you're having.  Try setting the Page's Scriptmanager's combinedscript property to false.